# If $E$ and $F$ are independent, does the following hold?

Tags: probability

If $E$ and $F$ are independent and $E = A \cup B$ and $F = A \cap B$ would the following statement be true?

$P(A \cap B) = 0$ or else $P(A' \cap B') = 0$

Comment: You don't need to speak about $A$ and $B$. Just assume $F\subseteq E$ and $F, E$ independent, and then ask: Must $P(F)=0$ or $P(E)=1$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes they would be. If $E = A \cup B$ and $F = A \cap B$, clearly $E \cap F = A \cup B \cap A \cap B = A \cap B = F$.Then

$$P(E \cap F) = P(F) =_{\text{independence}} P(E)P(F)$$

So it is either $P(F) = P(A \cap B) = 0$ or $P(E) = P(A \cup B) = 1$, but the last equality also implies $P( A^C \cap B^C) = 0$